# HotS - How can you redo a mission before finishing the campaign?

Tags: starcraft-2

Is there a way to redo a specific mission in the Heart of the Swarm campaign, before finishing the whole campaign (via Master Archives)? I know in WoL we could.

I'm asking this, because achievements are down right now and I would like to redo a mission to get the achiements before carrying on.

**EDIT**: I can't find where to redo a mission. I'm only at mission 3, is it later?

Comment: @Raven Dreamer: This is not exactly a duplicate. I'm asking if I can redo a misson BEFORE finishing the whole campaign.

Comment: Simon, if you will consider the duplicate question, it does not mention anything about finishing the campaign. Rather, he is talking about replaying an individual mission.

Comment: Simon, I'd suggest you repost your edit as a comment on [Aremer's answer.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/108483/336)

Comment: @SimonArsenault If you edited your question to ask if there are minimum requirements to replay missions, I would nominate it for reopening.  I believe the duped question is phrased from the perspective of "If I don't replay now, will I have another chance".  Your question seems more to be "I'm trying to replay now, how come I can't."  The requirement to complete missions before replay becomes available seems arbitrary and confusing - and at least for myself I see it as a unique question.